# MongoClient is not callable, but why?

Tags: python, flask, pymongo

in my Flask App I've imported pymongo with: `from pymongo import MongoClient`

Then I call my connect_db-method:

```
db = get_db(connect_db())
```

The method coding is like:

```
def connect_db():
    client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
    return client

def get_db(client):
    return client(DATABASE)
```

But I get the error `TypeError: 'MongoClient' object is not callable`

I find it on https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html

What's the reason?

Answer (score 7):

With pymongo you access a Client's database using attribute style access or dictionary style access:

```
def connect_db():
    client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
    return client

client = connect_db()
db = client.database_name
# or 
db = client['database-name']
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I must point out,mongoClient is not available in php7,pls be careful if you'r using this php version.